# Windows isn't generating Python Compiled Files

Tags: python, windows, pyramid

I'm currently on a Windows 7 environment developing a Pyramid web application.  I had been developing this app on my Mac, but that's recently died, so I've had to move to my Windows machine.

I've set up everything I need; Python 2.7, Pyramid, pyramid_beaker, MongoDB, mongoengine, etc.

It seemed to be working while I was editing the templates.  However, when I tried editing a view to add a new page to the app, it would not seem to be able to find it.  I added the following routes:

```
config.add_route('info_about','/info/about')
config.add_route('info_contact','/info/contact')
config.add_route('info_copyright','/info/copyright')
config.add_route('info_privacy','/info/privacy')
config.add_route('info_terms','/info/terms')
```

...which are handled by a view_config decorator like so:

```
@view_config(route_name='info_about', renderer="myproject:templates/info/about.mako", permission='all')
def info_about(request):
    <code goes here>
```

This is in an `info.py` file in the view subfolder (which does contain an `__init__.py` file).  This method has worked when I was on my Mac, but now that I've tried on Windows, it doesn't seem to work (it throws a 404 Not Found page up when trying to access it).

After a little investigating, I found that the `.pyc` version of `info.py` (the compiled version) does not exist.  `info.py` is new and was added on the Windows machine.  As a test, I tried editing a file created on the Mac and restarting the test server.  It hasn't modified the `.pyc` counterpart either, so I'm led to assume that Windows is not producing the `.pyc` version of the python files.

Is this a common problem, and more importantly, is there a solution? (I have to assume there is...)

Comment: .pyc files are just for faster imports of modules - you can safely ignore them , even delete them.  but if you're still interested to sus that out, what do you get if you go `import sys`; `print sys.dont_write_bytecode` ?  and if you are using a shortcut to python, check if it has the -B flag or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, your question is not clear enough. It seems you have some kind of read/write permission problems, and generating *.pyc has nothing to do with it.

*.pyc contains Python bytecode, in fact it is there just to load the original *.py files faster. Every time Python successfully reads a *.py file and is able to write(!) into the same directory, it creates a corresponding *.pyc file.

For more information see [compiled python files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files).

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining it.  I wasn't entirely clear on how that aspect of it worked (I never seemed to need to know before, although I probably should've).  I'll check the permissions.